# Python error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

This is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
def break_words(stuff):
"""This function will break up words."""
words = stuff.split(' ')
return words

def sort_words(words):
"""Sorts the words."""
return sorted(words)
def print_first_word(words):

def print_first_word(words):
"""Prints the first word after popping it off."""
word = raw_input('> ')
word = words.pop(0)
print word

def print_last_word(words):
"""Prints the last word after popping it off."""
word = words.pop(-1)
print word
```

When I call the script in Terminal, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 87, in <module>
    print_first_word(words)
  File "ex.py", line 15, in print_first_word
    word = words.pop(0)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

I don't understand this because, in a different file, I have basically identical code and I'm using pop in exactly the same context as here.
(this is an exercise from Learn Python The Hard Way exercise 26)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct as a string has no method pop, but you can convert print_first_word into a list.